# PHPExcel. Get border style of a cell

Tags: php, excel

I'm converting a XLS/XLSX file to HTML table and I'm trying to keep the embedded Excel styles saved in the XLS file. Up to now I managed to detect if a cell has certain styles:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("ExcelFile.xls");
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        $background_color = $cell->getStyle()->getFill()->getStartColor()->getRGB();
        $fore_color = $cell->getStyle()->getFont()->getColor()->getRGB();
        $font_bold = $cell->getStyle()->getFont()->getBold();
        $font_italic = $cell->getStyle()->getFont()->getItalic();
    }
}
```

But I can't find **how to detect if a cell has a border and what style the border is** (there's documentation about setting border but not retreiving borders).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
->getStyle('A1')->getBorders()->getTop()->getColor()->getRGB();
->getStyle('A1')->getBorders()->getTop()->getBorderStyle();
```

and so on...

:)

Comment: Hi, I tried as you said but echoing the result it reports that every cell has borders when actually only one cell has a border in my XLS file.

Comment: are you using $cell->getStyle()->getBorders()->getTop()->getBorderStyle(); ?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. My XLS file has only one cell with a visible black border. Every other cells "appears" not to have visible borders. By using `->getBorders()->getTop()->getColor()->getRGB();` I thought I should expect only once #000000. On the contrary it returns #000000 for every cell. If I use `->getBorders()->getTop()->getBorderStyle();` it returns always "none".

Comment: `foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        $background_color = $cell->getStyle()->getFill()->getStartColor()->getRGB();
        $fore_color = $cell->getStyle()->getFont()->getColor()->getRGB();
        $font_bold = $cell->getStyle()->getFont()->getBold();
        $font_italic = $cell->getStyle()->getFont()->getItalic();
        $bordo = $cell->getStyle()->getBorders()->getTop()->getBorderStyle();
    }
}`
sorry... not so used to stackoverflow...